# Why is `geom_area()` not displaying a graph but the same works for `geom_bar()`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset as shown below :

```
CounyByJobLength <- structure(list(JobAgeBins = c("< 1", ">10", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", 
                              "7-10"), CountByJobTime = c(157L, 45L, 491L, 517L, 50L, 238L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                        "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I have applied the below function to get a bar graph for the above observations

```
JobLengthPlot <- ggplot(CounyByJobLength,aes(x = JobAgeBins,y=CountByJobTime,fill=JobAgeBins))
JobLengthPlot <- JobLengthPlot + geom_bar(stat="identity")
JobLengthPlot <- JobLengthPlot + theme_bw()
plot(JobLengthPlot)
```

This is displaying me a proper bar graph:

[image]

But if I run a `geom_area()` statement, it does not populate the graph. What may be the possible reason?

```
JobLengthPlot <- ggplot(CounyByJobLength,aes(x = JobAgeBins,y=CountByJobTime,fill=JobAgeBins))
JobLengthPlot <- JobLengthPlot + geom_area(stat="identity")
JobLengthPlot <- JobLengthPlot + theme_bw()
plot(JobLengthPlot)
```

[image]

Comment: From the description of `geom_area()` : "An area plot is the continuous analog of a stacked bar chart (see geom_bar), and can be used to show how composition of the whole varies over the range of x."  Since you're working with categorical data it doesn't seem surprising that it doesn't work here. Your data doesn't define any margins on x for the different categories.

Comment: I don't see how an area graph would make sense here, especially since the different `fill`s will give one data point per level anyways. The best you can get is something like: `ggplot(CounyByJobLength,aes(x = as.numeric(as.factor(JobAgeBins)),y=CountByJobTime)) + geom_area(stat="identity")`, and then use `scale_x_continuous` to set the axis labels to what you want.